# Error en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, hosting, cpanel

es que desde la semana pasada me pidieron hacer unas copias de seguridad, pero al entrar a phpmyadmin me parece lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y no me deja acceder a nada, y la vdd no se que hacer.

al intentar hacer algo como `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'estampil'@'localhost'` por consola sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya intentastes manipular la bd desde consola?

Comment: Si y a todo lo que hago saca error

Comment: @Simon ya subi una imagen de lo que sale al meterme a la consola

Comment: configura las propiedades del usuario root   e.g. -

Answer (score 0):

configura las propiedades del usuario root   e.g. -

```
 GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@ WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 100
```

Establezca 0 para restablecer la limitación.

mas info [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836772/user-root-has-exceeded-the-max_questions-resource)

Comment: si te das cuenta al final de su pregunta, dice que al intentar ese comando le aparece otro error

Comment: Exacto @AlfredoPaz

Comment: @AlfredoPaz a perdon no lo habia visto, dejame ver